# VBA internet explorer data extract

Tags: vba, excel, href, getelementsbytagname

I have a VBA macro that I'm accessing IE through.  Then, I am looping through all the links on a site using doc.getElementsByTagName("a"), and for each link, I'm able to pull:
.innertext
.classname
.id
.href
.title

BUT, there are other datapoints listed within the "a" tag when I check "Inspect Element" in internet explorer. 
The two items I'm interested in are named "data-articletypeid" and "data-researchid." How would I pull these values?  They seem like unique items for this website.

Thanks,

Comment: Always show your code. Even when you think it's not relevant.

Comment: you need to know what attribute type (datapoint) this name applies to which means you need to know CSS and HTML ... then finding it should be easy ... perhaps provide a link to the specific webpage would help ... but definately these WILL often be site specific

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/    and     https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp   and   https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp

Comment: These are custom attributes - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp.  Is it possible to reference custom attributes in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the elements of the `<a>` tag, then loop through the attributes of the element and extract the attribute name through `nodeName`.

```
Dim elements, element, attr
Dim item As String

Set elements = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")

For Each element In elements
    For Each attr In element.Attributes
        Debug.Print attr.nodeName
    Next attr
Next element
```

"The Element interface represents an element in an HTML or XML document. Elements may have attributes associated with them; **since the Element interface inherits from Node, the generic Node interface attribute attributes may be used to retrieve the set of all attributes for an element**..."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869681(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  Thanks much.  What would the syntax be to pull the actual attribute name?  item = element.attributename?

Comment: Say I didn't know what to put where you have "data-animal-type," is it possible to pull a list of every attribute within the "a" elements?

Comment: Updated. You can now extract the attributes of an element.